# Can chrome extensions reach user submitted console commands?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm wondering if it's possible for installed chrome extensions to reach the contents of the console on any web page?

What I mean is - user submitted commands, for instance, when I open a website and enable console, and type in

```
let a = "mystring"
```

will chrome extensions reach this command I typed through the console?

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: Extensions can run an external utility that the user should install separately, see [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). This utility would be able to intercept OS keyboard input and send it to the extension.